# Views not respecting Contextual filter and Referenced Entity relationship

Tags: views, 8

This is driving me crazy because it's so simple in Drupal 7.

**Scenario:**

Basic page has a entity referenced field where you can type in Spotlights that should be shown at the bottom of the page.

**View**:

**Relationships** (in order) is the field_spotlights (which exists on the Basic Page) and field_spotlight: Content using the previous relationship.

**Contextual filter** is the ID of the node, based on current id of page. Uses the field_spotlights relationship

**Fields** are the fields that exist in the spotlight, each with a relationship with field_spotlight: Content.

So the above should show only 3 results if the basic page is viewed and only has 3 spotlights in the entity referenced field.

However 4+ spotlights are showing, it's including the 3 that should show but then duplicates some or shows more.

**UPDATE:**

I've tried using Aggregation too, by adding a Content ID to the fields, and setting the aggregation setting to Count, Count Distinct, and Max/Min.

Also tried setting Distinct in the query settings.

[image: screenshot of issue]

Comment: Is your site multilingual?

Comment: Nope, it’s a fairly basic build

Comment: Check that you don't have a Sort applied that may be causing the duplication...I've had that cause it for me.

Comment: no issue there. I thought of that too since there may be elements that are not set to the right, or any, relationship. I just included a screenshot.

Comment: I feel like you want a View of basic pages (so your filter criteria should be "type: Basic page") and then your contextual filter would also filter by the basic page's NID, and then you would bring in the Spotlight content as you have through the fields using relationships.

Comment: Just tried swapping the filter to page and it still shows spotlight content but incorrect amount of spotlights.

Comment: If you do it that way, you might not need both relationships. And try checking off and on the "require this relationship"

Comment: well look at that lol. By removing the basic page relationship, and setting the filter to basic page, and keeping the relationship for the fields. it works! You should add an Answer below so I can mark it for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want a View of basic pages (meaning filtered down to Content Type = Basic page) with a contextual filter narrowing down to the current Basic page using the Content ID (NID). Then add in a relationship to Spotlight through the entity reference field. And then for your three fields, make them use the Spotlight relationship.